# Golang losing precision while converting int to float32

Tags: go

Can anyone explain why the following conversion loses precision?

```
func main() {
    var a int32 = 1273478460 

    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Printf("%f \n", float64(a)) // 1273478460.000000, this is right number
    fmt.Printf("%f \n", float32(a)) // 1273478400.000000, this is wrong number
}
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are approximations: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This is not Go-specific. It loses precision because floating point is, well, floating point; because some of the bits are used for the exponent, there are fewer significand bits in a 32-bit float than there are in a 32-bit integer.

Comment: "Can anyone explain why the following conversion loses precision?" Yes. For the same reason `int16(a)` "loses precision": Not enough bits to store the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point trades *precision* for *range*. An IEEE-754 single precision (32-bit) float occupies 1 full 32-bit word (naturally). It has

- 1 sign bit,
- 8-bit exponent,
- 23-bit  mantissa

The largest integer than can be safely represented in a single precision float (due to the way the mantissa is represented, giving an implicit extra bit of precision) is **2<sup>24</sup>** (decimal 16,777,216); the smallest integer that can be safely represented is **- (2<sup>24</sup>)** (decimal -16,777,216). That gives a range of 33,554,433 integers.

For double precision floats (1 sign bit, 11-bit exponent, 52-bit mantissa) it's similar:

- min safe integer is **- (2<sup>53)</sup>** (decimal 9,007,199,254,740,992)
- max safe integer is **2<sup>53</sup>** (decimal 9,007,199,254,740,992)

See also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf). Published in *ACM Computing Surveys*, Vol 23, Number 1, March 1991. Essential reading.